# How to build a search api to find a specific company based on a keyword?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I am trying to build a search api using node.js to query and fetch data from mongodb to be displayed on an ios mobile app. This is my code so far. It is returning all the companies in the database. I only want it to return the top relevant companies when I test it on postman? For example, when I append Goo at the end of url, it should return all companies relevant to it such as google inc, google corp and goo

```
 api.get('/search/:name',(req,res) => {
    Company.find(req.params.name, (err, company) => {
      if(err){
        res.send(err);
      }
        res.json(company);
    });
});
```

Comment: Try reading [Query Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/) in the core documentation and come to terms with how you query for certain properties.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use RegExp, so it would be something like this:

```
 api.get('/search/:name',(req,res) => {
    Company.find({insert name of your field here: new RegExp('^' + req.params.name + '$', "i"), (err, company) => {
      if(err){
        res.send(err);
      }
        res.json(company);
    });
});
```

But you should keep on mind that you should cover cases when someone tries to "escape" with character such as "*" and "?" because they are considered as "special" chars in RegExp